# Mathematica refuses to distribute a scalar through parentheses

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation

I’m working on a problem involving Kelvin-Helmholtz instability and I’m trying to perform the linearization on *Mathematica*.  For some reason when I get to my first order equation (ε × stuff + O(ε²) == 0) and I ask *Mathematica* to divide by epsilon, it refuses to carry the operation through.  Here is my code:

```
Remove["Global`*"]; $Assumptions =.;
$Assumptions = {c > 0};

xx := {x, y, z} (*position vector*);
u := {ux[xx, t], uy[xx, t], uz[xx, t]} (*perturbation velocity*);
ρ1 := ϱ1[xx, t] (*perturbation density*);
P1 := p1[xx, t] (*perturbation pressure*);

(*Specify background flow:*)
v := {0, 0, vz[x]};
P0 := p0;
ρ0 := ϱ0[x];

(*Quantities of problem*)
SetAttributes[eps, Constant]
ρ := ρ0 + eps* ρ1;
P := P0 + eps* P1;
vv := v + eps*u;

(*Lagrangian (comoving) derivative*)
DDt[function_] := D[function,t] + Sum[ vv[[i]] D[#,xx[[i]]], {i,3}]& @(function)

(*Continuity, momentum and energy:*)
eqsOfMotion := {
   DDt[ρ] == -ρ Div[vv,xx],
   ρ DDt[vv] == -Grad[P,xx],
   DDt[P] == c^2 DDt[ρ]
   } ;

Print[Simplify[
  eqsOfMotion /. eps -> 0], "-> background flow is valid solution"]

(*Since background flow is valid solution 
we have that every term in eqsOfMotion is 
proportional to eps, hence can divide through:*)
eqsOfMotion/eps
```

And that last line is where my problem arises. The `1/eps` term refuses to pass through the parentheses and cancel with `eps`.  Any ideas?

My version of *Mathematica* is 11.3.

Comment: See `DivideSides` in documentation, looks to have been introduced in 11.3. Equations do not automatically absorb arithmetic operations.

Comment: Or if `DivideSides` is not available: `eqsOfMotion2 = eqsOfMotion /. Equal[lhs_, rhs_] :> Equal[lhs/eps, rhs/eps] // Simplify`

Comment: @eyorble `DivideSides` does not quite work for me, as it adds in too much complexity, but by leafing through the documentation for it I found a method that works with `ApplySides` — thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Following @eyorble's suggestion to look at `DivideSides`, I found that a method that does the trick is

```
ApplySides[#/eps&, eqsOfMotion]
```

(and apparently another valid solution replaces `ApplySides` with `Map`, but I couldn’t get it to work).

`DivideSides` does *not* work for me because it is too intelligent for its own good, and creates a proliferation of cases in which I have no interest.